# splitting and recombining lists in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has columns containing lists:

```
0                                 [Boeing]                    [sells]   
1   [aircrafts, they, agreement, airplane]  [are, built, made, built]   
2                       [exception, these]                 [are, are]   
3                        [sales, contract]       [regulated, consist]   
4                               [contract]               [stipulates]   
5                            [acquisition]                      [has]   
6                               [contract]                  [managed]   
7                               [employee]                      [act]   
8                    [salesperson, Boeing]          [change, ensures]   
9                     [airlines, airlines]            [related, have]   
10                                [Boeing]                     [keep]
```

I want to rearange my data so that the lists in each column of my dataframe are unpacked and combined with the corresponding items from the unpacked next column.

The result for the first two rows in my example should look like this:

```
0                                 [Boeing]                    [sells]   
1                                 [aircrafts]                 [are]  
2                                 [they]                      [built] 
3                                 [agreement]                 [made]
4                                 [airplane]                  [built]
```

How can this be done? Note that my dataframe contains 5 columns in total.

Comment: Do we know each sublist is the same length in each column?

Comment: No, the sublists are of a variable length.